# entity framework execute SQL before migrations

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am working on an existing project that uses Entity-Framework 6 with code-first.  I have a need to run some SQL before the migrations run.

I have a DbMigrationsConfiguration class with a seed method, but seed runs after the migrations.

I think it will work if I run my SQL in the constructor but I can't get a reference to the context.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 26):

You could use the 'Sql' method within the desired migration class.

```
public partial class OneOfYourMigrations : DbMigration 
{ 
    public override void Up() 
    { 
        //EF generated migration code here such as
        //CreateTable or AddColumn etc...
        //Now run your custom sql - here I'm doing an update to an existing column
        Sql("UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET Column1 = 'VALUE1' "); 
    } 

    public override void Down() 
    { 
        //EF generated code to rollback
    } 
}
```

So the steps are;

- Generate migration class using Add-Migration
- Alter the class using code similar to above
- Run the migration using Update-Database

Comment: Can you explain more detail?  I thought migrations run once and only once.  This would work if it will run every time but it only seems to run one time.

Comment: May be I could be more specific if I knew what kind of SQL you want to run? Is it modification of data (like I mentioned above) or is it something else? FYI, a given migration runs once against a given db, but you can always roll back a given migration - change it (i.e Add Sql) and run it again.

Comment: Want to run a script? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125937/can-we-run-sql-script-using-code-first-migrations