# How to run sql script with Entity Framework in .NET Core 1.0?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I'd like to run sql scripts in an ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0 project. The answer here: [Can we run sql script using code first migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125937/can-we-run-sql-script-using-code-first-migrations)
pretty much explains exactly what I want to do, except that for this line:

```
Sql(File.ReadAllText(sqlFile));
```

it barks and says *"The name 'Sql' does not exist in the current context"*.
I'm sure there must be a way in .NET Core 1.0.
I'm just getting started with .NET Core 1.0, so it may be something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
private class SomeMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(File.ReadAllText(sqlFile));
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet. That worked great. In case anyone else comes across it, I did have to remove the "GO" statements from my script for it to work. Thanks @Konstantin!