# How can I add a check constraint for JSON in Entity Framework?

Tags: json, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2016, code-first

Adding a `JSON CHECK CONSTRAINT`for a table field with

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Data]  
   ADD CONSTRAINT [JsonData must be formatted as JSON] 
   CHECK  (IsJson([JsonData]) > 0)
```

works fine, but I want to make it work for Code First.

I have tried the `Reverse Engineering Code First`, but it does not help me with this problem. Executing a Sql Command with the same code `(Seed() method)` works very well, but this is not one of the solutions I would like to use:

```
protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
{
    context
    .Database
    .ExecuteSqlCommand(
        "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Data]  
            ADD CONSTRAINT [JsonData must be formatted as JSON] 
            CHECK  (IsJson([JsonData]) > 0)");
}
```

Is there any other way I can add a `JSON Check Constraint` from Code First?

Comment: You can do it with [raw sql in code first migration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32125937/1042934)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that EF don't support any kind of CHECK constraints. The only thing that you can use is migration. See example in: [Is it possible to add CHECK constraint with fluent API in EF7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245449/is-it-possible-to-add-check-constraint-with-fluent-api-in-ef7)

Comment: Sorry for such a long time until I marked this as `Accepted Answer`.

Answer (score 6):

As per the accepted answer, you'll need to add a migration. This is the EF Core syntax:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Data ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Data_JsonData_MustBeJson CHECK (IsJson(JsonData) = 1);");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Applications DROP CONSTRAINT CK_Data_JsonData_MustBeJson;");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In EFCore 3+ this is now possible.

(*Note: [ISJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is only available for SQL Server 2016+*)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        var tableIdentifier = StoreObjectIdentifier.Create(entityType, StoreObjectType.Table);
        foreach (var entityProperty in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (entityProperty.PropertyInfo != null && Attribute.IsDefined(entityProperty.PropertyInfo, typeof(JsonAttribute), inherit: true))
            {
                var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
                var columnName = entityProperty.GetColumnName(tableIdentifier.Value);
                modelBuilder.Entity(clrType).HasCheckConstraint(
                    name: $"CK_{tableName}_{columnName}_JSON",
                    sql: $"ISNULL(ISJSON({columnName}), 1) = 1"
                );
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

The `JsonAttribute` is just a simple marker that I used for convenience:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class JsonAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Usage:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Json]
    public string JsonData { get; set; }
}
```

Another possible alternative to using attributes would be using your own "convention" (e.g. property that is string and has a "Json" prefix/suffix)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that now (EFCore 3+) you can also use fluent api to declare a json check constraint.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder builder) {  
base.OnModelCreating (builder);

// gets the configurations
builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// adds cinstraint checks
builder.Entity<Settings>(e => e.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Set_JSONDocument_JSON","JSON_VALID(JSONDocument)" ));
}
```