How do I separate seeding data from migration code in order to reduce the size of .Designer files
We have a large business application that has large amount of seed data in Entity Framework Core 8. DbContext is a separate library that is linked into web application as a nuget package. We apply seed data as part of migrations (in ef database update).
Everything works fine, but every time there is a new migration, EF creates .Designer.cs file that is 9MB large. Most of that file is seed data. For testing I removed seed data from the project and the file is 20 times smaller. After 30-40 migrations it takes much longer to compile. Therefore, every 4-5 months we "flatten" migrations. It works - but there got to be a better way.
We do maintain/modify both model definitions and seed data. Is there a way to reduce the size of the designer files?
I don't know if any code would be helpful to add to the problem definition. Here is the example:
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        ...
    }
}

public partial class MyDbContext {       

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasData(new Location
        { ... }
        );
    }
}

In fact, in the seed code we may have a 500-item list with some setup data; but in designer file it's all split into individual inserts, making the file huge.

Why don't u externalize that seed data into an SQL script file ? This answer can help u on how to execute it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035754/how-to-run-migration-sql-script-using-entity-framework-core

@DA - for the same reason we keep all other Model-related information in C# code. It's much easier to track, and EF migrations calculate the delta automatically. I don't think I need to explain the benefits of Entity Framework in this question. I just want to find a way to reduce the size of .Designer.cs files

One approach to mitigate this issue is to separate the seed data from the migration scripts generated by Entity Framework Core. Instead of including the seed data directly in the migrations, you can manage the seed data separately and apply it after migrations have been applied or during application startup.

If your seed is so huge, you should probably think about a dedicated code stored outside of DB Context and entity configuration. You could replicate the __EFMigrationsHistory table but instead of migrations, store versions of your custom seed operations. Every time application starts check whether all seed operations have been applied, if not, run the ones that haven't been applied yet. After running, save it in the table. Store your seed operations as C# code with injectable DB Context or custom SQL (whatever the preference/need).

@Rena - I assume you mean to keep seed data outside DBContext in order to exclude it from migrations. I like the idea; but I haven't figure out how to do that while maintaining the convenience of leaving to EF to generate delta when we change seed data?

@Prolog - same comment: I definitely thought about it, but I haven't figured out how to do that while maintaining the convenience of leaving to EF to generate delta when we change seed data. Any pointers?
