# Update data in existing column with EF Core Migration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

My table in SQL has two fields: Id and Status. It looks something like this

ID | Status

1  | "Status1"

2  | "Status2"

I should make a migration that will change those status values into those that I want?
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use a plain SQL script to update the data values. It can be added to a migration file. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: It should be done using migration builder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we run SQL script using code first migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125937/can-we-run-sql-script-using-code-first-migrations)

Comment: I'm looking for different answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I should make a migration that will change those status values into those that I want?

Try add SQL statements  into `Up` method of the generated migration file manually like below

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
        migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE A SET AName = 'Jhon' WHERE Id=3");
}
```

For updating multiple records , you could refer to the following code

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
        migrationBuilder.Sql(
           "UPDATE A SET AName = CASE Id " +
                   "WHEN 1 THEN 'Shariy' " +
                   "WHEN 2 THEN 'Mary'" +
                   "ELSE AName END " +
                   "WHERE Id IN(1,2)");
}
```